# Visual studio 2017 cshtml syntax highlighting not working

Tags: visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2017

I have been using VS 2015 for quite some time and just moved to 2017 recently. My cshtml text is all one color (black) and I have been trying to figure out why they are not highlighting like my other file types. Any ideas? This is pretty frustrating as I have been through different settings and many posts looking for an answer. I must be missing something.

Comment: No one knows the issue?

Comment: Not sure what you have tried, but I would suggest resetting all options to default, repairing your VS2017 install (or doing a clean install). Also search for a file 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.err' and see if it has anything in it (mostly likely some DLLs not loading, etc). Like I said without more information on what you have done already, can't help more.

Comment: I just did a clean install on a different machine, and I'm seeing this issue, same as VS2015. 

Wonder if there's something in the solution file itself causing this.

Comment: I looked in VS 2015 and intellisense works fine there. It only doesn't work in VS 2017 now for me :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The repair tip actually worked. I was not aware that you could repair your instance... Thank you for the help!

To repair, go to "Programs and Features", select "Microsoft Visual Studion 2017" and  choose "Change".  The Repair option is shown here:

[image]

Comment: I am seeing this same issue with the VS 2017 version 6. I repaired and it worked. I then installed Powershell Tools (using Modify button), the coloring was gone again. Tried repairing again and no luck this time :(

Comment: Repairing worked for me as well. Syntax highlighting for .cshtml files broke after I installed the 15.9.12 update. Ran the Repair option and it fixed it!

Answer (score 3):

Select all (Ctrl+A) and Copy(Ctrl+C) everything in the .cshtml file.
Delete everything! Save (Ctrl+S) the empty file. Then paste (Ctrl+P). Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I have solved it by installing "Web Essentials 2017".
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebExtensionPack2017

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen (and I have tested it with several machines) when VS 2017 does not have access to the installation cache. Somtimes one would like to download the installer files and keep the workload layout after installation; you then need the cache available somewhere. You may move the installation cache to a drive of your choice but remember that system and administrator must have access (everyone read access), and modify the registry setting to reflect the relocation of the files: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup 
There you set CachePath to your new path and it will be alright. Hope this helps